# Date and timestamps behaving strangely in PHP when adding a day

Tags: php, date

I need to add one day to a date using Timestamps. The following code should work but it doesn't :

```
$date = '2014-10-26';
$date_timestamp = strtotime($date);                // Converting the date to timestamp
$new_date_timestamp = $date_timestamp + 24*60*60;  // Adding one day
$new_date = date("Y-m-d",$new_date_timestamp);     // Formating the new date
```

It returns $new_date = '2014-10-26' instead of 2014-10-27.

Strangely, it works well for other dates. For example, if $date = '2014-10-28', then it returns $new_date = '2014-10-29', as it should.

I am completely stuck. Any idea to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the system in England? [British Summer Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time) ended on the 26th at 0100. I think this could account for the discrepancy: during BST, the time is GMT+1. In order to return to GMT, you therefore subtract one hour. 0100 becomes 0000, effectively making 10/26 25 hours long.

Comment: I live in France. That could be the reason! Amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty weird, try with  this instruction:

```
$new_date_timestamp = strtotime("+1 day", $date_timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily accomplished with strtotime:

```
$date     = '2014-10-26';
$new_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+ 1 day", strtotime($date)));
echo $new_date;
```